# jQuery why $(this) doesn't work in a setTimeout method?

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery code:

```
$('#loadingDiv2')
.css('visibility','hidden')  // hide it initially
.ajaxStart(function() {
    $(this).css('visibility','visible');
    $("#bbdata").empty();
})
.ajaxStop(function() {
    $(this).css('visibility','hidden');// works here 
setTimeout(function(){
    $(this).css('visibility','hidden');// doesn't work here
    }, 100);
});
```

why $(this) doesn't work in a setTimeout method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because `this` is a different context at that point (`window`), you have a few optons though, store a reference to what you want to deal with, like this:

```
.ajaxStop(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  setTimeout(function(){
    $this.css('visibility','hidden');
  }, 100);
});
```

Or use [`$.proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) for to set the context in that anonymous function, like this:

```
.ajaxStop(function() {
  setTimeout($.proxy(function(){
    $(this).css('visibility','hidden');
  }, this), 100);
});
```

In the first solution we store a reference to what we want to deal with, in the second we're actually setting that `this` is when that function runs...otherwise it'll be `window`.

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue with `this` in `setTimout`, it's clarified in [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout#The_%27this%27_problem).
But that's not big deal, you can always use `var that = this;` trick.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` runs in the global context, where `this` refers to the window object.

Try storing a reference to this instead:

```
.ajaxStop(function() {
    var me = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(me).css('visibility','hidden');
    }, 100);
});
```